# How can I track why files are getting deleted on my Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, filesystems

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running a third-party web app.  The web app generates log files and those log files are getting randomly deleted.  The vendor support isn't able to reproduce the issue (nor am I in my lab).  I'm suspecting that another third-party app/tool may be deleting the files but I'd like to confirm.

Is there a tool I can use to track what specific process deleted a file?

I was initially thinking I could enable an audit policy for the directory (as per http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/08/27/auditing-file-access-on-file-servers.aspx) but group policy restrictions are in place and prevent me from doing this.

I then thought that I could use something like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) but that doesn't seem to track deletions.

Is there any other tool/method I can use to track deletions?

Comment: Can you not talk with whoever setup the restricting GPO?  Ask them to change the policy or create an exception?

Comment: @Zoredache I'm looking into that now but change management makes it time consuming.  Was wondering if there's another alternative I could pursue in parallel here so I don't need to wait.

Comment: Off topic but related: If your change management process on something you manage is time consuming then you do not have change management you have process controls.  You have problems diagnosing this because you do not have change management, s this should just be a standard change

Comment: @JimB  I understand and agree however I don't have control over the change management process (such as it is).  Is there an alternate technical solution I can pursue in the meantime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and set up a filter with the options of Detail is `Delete: True`

It's going to pick up a bunch of temp files so it's probably also a good idea to make another filter for only the path containing the files

[image]

Comment: Bingo! That was it.  Thanks - I'm not sure why it wasn't showing up for me earlier.